# Ошибка запроса fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysqli_query(connect_db(),"SELECT MAX(owner_id) FROM owner"));

echo $row['owner_id'];
```

Пишет, что ждал параметр, а получил обьект.
Результ запроса потом мне еще в переменную скинуть надо

Comment: Исправил mysqli.   как получить значение в переменную?

Comment: А как вы хотите функцией драйвера mysql обработать объект mysqli?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_query` возвращает объект [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.mysqli-result.php), который Вы почему-то пытаетесь обработать функцией устаревшего драйвера `mysql_fetch_arrray`

```
$row = mysqli_query(connect_db(),"SELECT MAX(owner_id) FROM owner");

$data = $row->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $data["owner_id"];
```

Либо процедурно, как написано в мануале. Но если вкратце - Вы ошиблись на один символ в названии функции